# how to pass value from list of maps in gsp to action?

Tags: list, grails, dictionary, row, parameters

```
<g:each  in="${flist}"> <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <td align="center"><g:link controller="spider" action="ThirdPage" params="${it.get('dt')}">
            ${it.get('dt')}</g:link>
            </td></tr>
```

wher flist is list of maps.now i want to pass dt which is key in map within list to controller action.i tried it with above codes but its not working.what mistake i am doing there.

Thanks in advance,
laxmi

Answer (score 1):

Your params should be a map. Looks like you are passing a value in params. you need to send a map in params.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that flist is of type `List<Map>`? have you tried to print out the flist params? are you sure that you have closed the each tag?

```
<g:link controller="spider" action="ThirdPage" params="[paramName: it.get('dt')]">${it.get('dt')}</g:link>
```

be careful that you pass the link params in the right way.